# Delegate pattern use but ı get Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value Error Message

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I clone the project yesterday and it is include two ViewControllers and SelectionScreen send data to BaseScreen with Delegate Design pattern.Here is my first code is seperated from Controllers

```
import UIKit

class BaseScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var chooseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chooseButton.layer.cornerRadius = chooseButton.frame.size.height/2
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBAction func chooseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectionScreen") as! SelectionScreen
        selectionVC.selectionDelegate=self
        present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension BaseScreen: SideSelectionDelegate {
    
    func didTapChoice(image: UIImage, name: String, color: UIColor) {
        mainImageView.image = image
        nameLabel.text = name
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
    
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

protocol SideSelectionDelegate {
    func didTapChoice(image: UIImage, name: String, color: UIColor)
}

class SelectionScreen: UIViewController {
    
    var selectionDelegate: SideSelectionDelegate!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func imperialButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(image: UIImage(named: "vader")!, name: "Darth Vader", color: .red)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func rebelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(image: UIImage(named: "luke")!, name: "Luke Skywalker", color: .cyan)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and this makes perfect but when ı change to this

```
import UIKit

class BaseScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var chooseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chooseButton.layer.cornerRadius = chooseButton.frame.size.height/2
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBAction func chooseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectionScreen") as! SelectionScreen
     **//   selectionVC.selectionDelegate=self**
        present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


extension BaseScreen: SideSelectionDelegate {
    
    func didTapChoice(image: UIImage, name: String, color: UIColor) {
        mainImageView.image = image
        nameLabel.text = name
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
    
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

protocol SideSelectionDelegate {
    func didTapChoice(image: UIImage, name: String, color: UIColor)
}

class SelectionScreen: UIViewController {
    
    var selectionDelegate: SideSelectionDelegate!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func imperialButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        **let vc=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BaseScreen") as! BaseScreen
        self.selectionDelegate=vc**
        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(image: UIImage(named: "vader")!, name: "Darth Vader", color: .red)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func rebelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        **let vc=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BaseScreen") as! BaseScreen
        self.selectionDelegate=vc**
        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(image: UIImage(named: "luke")!, name: "Luke Skywalker", color: .cyan)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I get this error

[image]

Can anyone help me I know its been too long but in my opinion solution is too easy
Thanks for everything

Comment: Your problematic code is creating a **NEW** instance of `BaseScreen` view controller, setting `self.selectionDelegate` to that **NEW** instance, and then (if you did not get the error) your code throws away that new instance. So, first question: ***why*** do you want to make that change?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: ı wanna solve this data transportation in different approach.I think that delegate will be work perfect whether instance in basescreen or sharescreen but ı dont work.Thanks advice.But ı wanna have other question.Actualy delegate work even if ı do this bad instance.I could print data perfectly but it crashed when ı try to change labeltext WHY? @DonMag

Comment: thx @matt it is huge advise for me .I have same question which ı asked above

Comment: @Sait47 - that's really not clear... Are you saying your `BaseScreen` may be showing, and you present `SelectionScreen` -- at which point tapping "Rebel Button" should dismiss Selection Screen and update Base Screen... **AND** you want to be showing `SelectionScreen` and, tapping "Rebel Button" should show `BaseScreen` as a share screen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27gom.png You say that ı created new Base Screen in ShareScreen but as you can see in doc even if ı created new BaseScreen it is still My main Base screen delegate is trigger How can be possible? @DonMag

Comment: @Sait47 - it doesn't help to show an image of your code. Your approach is incorrect. You need to answer my question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ı just want to know one thing and ıt is not link with your questions.As you say ı init new BaseScreen and it is not my Main BaseScreen And here is my question.Even if ı init new BaseScreen delegate is still trigger my method like(print name) but when ı set label text ı get error Why? In my opinion if my new BaseScreen include method it has also include label and other UI items.They are not supposed to be nil.I hope it will clear this time @DonMag

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`@IBOutlet` elements are not available until a view has loaded.

If you add this line, you won't get the "unexpectedly found nil..." error:

```
@IBAction func rebelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BaseScreen") as! BaseScreen

    // add this line to force the controller to load its view NOW       
    vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
    
    self.selectionDelegate=vc
    selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(image: UIImage(named: "luke")!, name: "Luke Skywalker", color: .cyan)
    
}
```

However, as soon as that code executes, the new instance of `BaseScreen` will cease to exist. So it will not accomplish anything.

You could, though, at that point, call `present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`, for example.

Comment: Now my problem is done thanks to you @DonMag